# How to reset Administrator password in Windows Server 2019?

Tags: passwords, reset, windows-server-2019

I've seen ways of using boot media to reset utilsman, but I think this backdoor has been closed now.

It's a fresh installation, but somehow I changed the password and have no record of it.
So I only have access as a user, not as administrator, and want to avoid having to reinstall.

Any suggestions please?

Is there a way to just reveal the password using some linuxy app on a flashdrive?

Comment: I'd try the NT offline password editor before assuming it can't work. its had surprising longevity and unless you are using bitlocker, I think it will probably work. https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

Comment: Yeah, but floppies though?!

Comment: So this is not like a .iso to make a bootable flashdrive with Rufus.ie  How to make an bootable USB drive
Copy all the files that is inside the usbXXXXXX.zip or on the CD onto an usb drive, directly on the drive, not inside any directory/folder.
It is OK if there are other files on the USB drive from before, they will not be removed.
Install bootloader on the USB drive, from command prompt in windows (start the command line with "run as administrator" if possible)
X:syslinux.exe -ma X:
Replace X: with the drive letter the USB drive shows up as (DO NOT USE C:)

Comment: no dude, use the CD iso or usb.  https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html

Comment: ah yeah, sorry it's CD release, with the iso file for Rufus

cd140201.zip (~18MB) - Bootable CD image. (md5sum: f274127bf8be9a7ed48b563fd951ae9e)

Comment: it doesn't work... doesn't boot.... even when I select safe mode with command prompt, I just get normal boot, and no working options other than reset password, and it's not a password reset usb

Comment: The most I can do at the moment is log in with a non Administrator account; or boot to a USB with Windows Server ISO on it, and go into repair my PC screens and CMD there. I don't seem to be able to find utilsman, so that seems to be a dead end at the moment.

Comment: Are we talking about the built-in Administrator account or an Administrator account that you created? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: The tool I recommended is a text only menu driven interface, you boot into INSTEAD of windows. make sure your firmware is configured to boot from USB, and perhaps use the firmware boot menu to select your usb drive at boot time.